# Prove that the set $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is equipotent to the set $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Please can proof the following statement?

> $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is [equipotent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Equipotent.html) to the set $\mathbb R$, where $\mathbb R$ is the real numbers.

Comment: Usc Schroder-Bernstein Theorem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $|\mathbb{R}$| = |$\mathbb{R^2}$| = ... = |$\mathbb{R^\infty}$|?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948908/is-mathbbr-mathbbr2-mathbbr-infty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There clearly is an injection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. By Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein, it suffices to find an injection $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which is the same as finding an injection $(0,1)\times(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$, because $\mathbb{R}$ is equipotent to $(0,1)$.

If $r\in(0,1)$, let $0.r_1r_2\dots r_n\dots$ be its unique decimal development (not eventually $9$, to have uniqueness, but eventually $0$ allowed).

To a pair $\langle r,s\rangle\in(0,1)\times(0,1)$, associate
$$
0.r_1s_1r_2s_2\dots r_ns_n\dots\in(0,1)
$$
The given decimal development cannot be eventually $9$ and from it it's possible to get back $r$ and $s$. So the mapping is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following map:
Take the unique decimal representation of a Real (standard assumptions to get it unique, no infinite sequence of nines for instance.)
\begin{equation}
x=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_k\cdot 10^k
\end{equation}
and assign it the following vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{2k}\cdot 10^k,\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{2k-1}\cdot 10^k\right).
\end{equation}

**EDIT** the following is wrong (see Ujan's comment) but the mapping is still surjective which is enough to have:
"This clearly defines a bijection since you can easily write down the inverse."

Comment: Decimal representation is not exactly unique as you can write 1.000...=0.999... Unless you specify what are you using the function is not well defined. Even if you take one convention and make the function well defined, the same problem will occur while proving the function is bijective.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Your last point is true @Ujan, I will edit that. But the mapping is surjective which still is enough.

Comment: @Max I agree that the map is onto. But why is it enough? The map is not one-one now as both $0.909090...$ and $10$ are mapped to $(0,10)$.

Comment: it is enough since by $\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto\left(x,0\right)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ we have that $\mathrm{card}\left(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\right)\geq \mathrm{card}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ and by my answer we have equality.

Comment: @Max But we can not treat $card(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})$ and $card(\mathbb{R})$ as real numbers. What you are doing is precisely the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroder Theorem.